# Systems of Linear Differential Equations - Is this Correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve the following first-order linear system, $x(t)$ represents one population and the $y(t)$ represents another population that lives in the same ecosystem: (Note: $'$ denotes prime)

Note: $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ must be found using the Reduction method.

$x'=−5x−20y$ (Equation 1)

$y'=5x+7y$ (Equation 2)

I start off with finding the derivative of (Equation 1) which gives me:

$x''=−5x'−20y'$

and then substitute $y'$ using the equations above (Equation 2):

$x''=−5x'−20(5x+7y)$

foil expansion:

$x''=−5x'−100x−140y$ (Equation 3)

so I find by by using (Equation 1):

$$
\begin{align}
x' &=-5x-20y\\
x'+5x &= -20y\\
\frac{x'+5x}{-20} &= y\\
y&=- \frac 1 {20}(x'+5x)
\end{align}$$

After finding this y, I insert it into (Equation 3)

$x''=-5x'-100x-140(-\frac 1 {20}(x'+5x))$

And expand thus getting:

$$x''=-5x'-100x+7x'+35x$$

Collect 'like' terms and put on LHS.

$$x''-2x'+65x = 0$$

Then put into auxillary form:

$$r^(2)−2r+65=0$$

Find roots:

$$r=1±8i$$

I can now say that $x(t)= C_1 e^t \sin8t + C_2 e^t \cos8t$ (Note: $\frac {C_1} {C_2}$ are constants)

Which I simplified to: 
$$x(t) = e^t(C_1 \sin8t + C_2 \cos8t)$$

Now I need $y(t)$. I will begin with finding the derivative of $x(t)$.
$$
x'(t) = e^t((C_1-8C_2)\sin8t + (8C_1+C_2)\cos8t)$$

$$x'(t) = e^t (C_1 \sin8t - 8C_2 \sin8t + 8C_1 \cos8t + C_2 \cos8t)$$

I input this into the original equation (Equation 1):

$x'=3x-5y$ now becomes

$$e^t C_1 \sin8t - e^t 8C_2\sin8t + e^t8C_1 \cos8t + e^t C_2 \cos8t = -5 (e^t C_1 \sin8t + e^t C_2 \cos8t - 20(b(t))$$

I expand, collect 'like' terms, find LCD, and determine that:

$$b(t) = \dfrac{4C_2 e^t \sin8t - 4 C_1 e^t \cos8t - 3 C_1 e^t \sin8t - 3 C_2 e^t \cos8t}{10} $$

My question: Are my $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ correct using the methods shown above (which is represented using an example in my book).

Comment: Do you know the matrix techniques?

Comment: No, the book describes using this method (Reduction method). : (

Comment: Check this [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450159/differential-equation-by-systematic-elimination/450834#450834). I do not know why this question was deleted!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have:

$$x(t) = e^{t}(c_1 \sin(8t) + c_2 \cos(8t))$$

Now, we want to solve:

$$y(t) = -\dfrac{1}{20}\left(x'(t) + 5 x(t)\right)$$

We get:

- $x'(t) = e^t (c_1 \sin (8 t)+ c_2 \cos (8 t))+e^t (8 c_1 \cos (8 t)-8 c_2 \sin (8 t))$
- $5 x(t) = 5 e^t (c_1 \sin (8 t) + c_2 \cos (8 t)) $
- $x'(t) + 5 x(t) = 6 e^t (c_1 \sin (8 t)+c_2 \cos (8 t))+e^t (8 c_1 \cos (8 t)-8 c_2 \sin (8 t))$
- $y(t) = -\dfrac{1}{20}\left(x'(t) + 5 x(t)\right) =$

$$-\dfrac{1}{20}(6 e^t (c_1 \sin (8 t)+c_2 \cos (8 t))+e^t (8 c_1 \cos (8 t)-8 c_2 \sin (8 t)))$$

Simplification yields:

$$y(t) = -\dfrac{1}{10} e^t ((3 c_1-4 c_2) \sin (8 t)+(4 c_1+3 c_2) \cos (8 t))$$

Now, you can verify that these solutions **simultaneously** solve your system by calculating $x'(t)$ and verifying that it equals $(−5x(t)−20y(t))$ **and** finding $y'(t)$ and verifying that it equals $(5x(t)+7y(t))$.

The more general approach to solve these problems is the matrix approach with eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful, thank you.

Comment: You are very welcome and great job showing your work! Regards

Answer (score 1):

[Related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450159/differential-equation-by-systematic-elimination/450834#450834). Here is the technique I referred to in the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450159/differential-equation-by-systematic-elimination/450834#450834) in my comment. the system

$$ x'=-5x-20y \\ 
y'= 5 x + 7 y $$

can be written as

$$\implies Dx+5x+20y=0 \\ 
\quad \quad Dy-7y -5x = 0, $$

where $D=\frac{d}{dt}$. Rearranging the above system yields

$$\implies (D+5)x+20y=0 \\ 
\quad \quad  -5x + (D-7)y = 0 \longrightarrow (*). $$

Multiplying the first equation in $(*)$ by $5$ and applying the operator $D+5$ to the second equation in $(*)$, then adding the two equations results in a second order ode in $y$.

I think you can carry on the calculations.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this.

Comment: @user2312844: You are welcome.