# diferential equation system differential operators method

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, derivatives

$x'-3x+2y=t$

$y'+2x=e^t$

it is asked to solve by the mentioned method

$\Delta(D)=D(D-5)$

$\Delta_1=1-e^t$

$\Delta_2=-2t-2e^t$

$yD^3(D-5)(D-1)=0$

$xD^2(D-5)(D-1)=0$

When solving for the original system with the obtained $x$ and $y$ functions it gives me impossible.

Can you see what is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: @Amzoti yes...it is only given the system (1st two equations)

Comment: @Amzoti by operator form you mean $\Delta(D)x_i=\Delta_i$? i did it

Comment: mistaked a D by a 2 in that part...thanks

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/751289/systems-of-linear-differential-equations-is-this-correct/751396#751396).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first find the particular solution, say, by undetermined constants. that is you try a solution of the form $$x = A + Bt + Ce^t, y = D + E + Fe^t$$  plug it in the system of differential equations and equate the coefficients of $1, t, e^t$ to determine all the constants.

let us look at the associated homogeneous system: $$x^\prime - 3x + 2y =0, y^\prime  + 2x = 0$$ this system can be written symbolically 
$$(D-3)x + 2y = 0, Dy + 2x = 0 \text{ where $D$ is the operator $\frac{d}{dt}$ }$$

we can eliminate $y$ from the two if you multiply the first by $2D$ and the second by $2$ and subtracting you get $$D(D-3)x- 4x = (D^2-3D-4)x =(D +1)(D-4)x=0$$ the solution is $$x = Ae^{4t} + Be^{-t}, y = -{1 \over 2}(D-3)x = -{A \over 2 }e^{4t} + B e^{-t}$$

to these you add the particular solutions you found earlier. hope this helps.